# How to automatically load a report on home page after logged in Jasper Server Community

Tags: jasperserver

In Jasper Server Community Edition, I want to load a report automatically without clicking on any report when I logging. I tried to add below code to **home.jsp** page as jasperSoft documentation says.but it is not working.

Please help me with this.

**Code that I added to home.jsp :-**

```
<% 
<authz:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_REPORT_HOME"> 
<c:redirect
    url="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports&reportUnit=%2Freports%2FSample_Dash_Report&standAlone=true"/> 
</authz:authorize>
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Jasper server installation directory and search for ***jasperserver-servlet.xml*** (C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.2\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\jasperserver-servlet.xml)
2. Under ***bean id = "homePageByRole"*** we have to make changes. For that, search homePageByRole word inside the ***jasperserver-servlet.xml*** file.
3. Under  tag ,we can give a report link we need according to the user roles. But make sure you should add **amp;** as after each **&** mark. Otherwise it will give an error!

   Example:-

   **Original report link from the address bar in browser when report opened using jasper server is;**
   http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2FMy_Reports&reportUnit=%2FMy_Reports%2FDashboard_Report_Landscape&standAlone=true

   **But the link we should put under  is;**
   ROLE_USER|redirect:/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2FMy_Reports&reportUnit=%2FMy_Reports%2FDashboard_Report_Landscape&standAlone=true

   check how we add as **amp;** after every **&** mark. Also we can set user role. In my case I set user role as ***ROLE_USER***.

**Whole code snippet is;**

```
<bean id="homePageByRole" class="java.util.ArrayList">
            <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.util.Collection">
                <list>
                    <value>ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR|redirect:/flow.html?_flowId=searchFlow</value>
                    <value>ROLE_USER|redirect:/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&amp;_flowId=viewReportFlow&amp;ParentFolderUri=%2FMy_Reports&amp;reportUnit=%2FMy_Reports%2FDashboard_Report_Landscape&amp;standAlone=true</value>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to follow all the steps in the tutorial, as you probably missed to add user role to the user you want. Also, make sure to have sample data as you're referencing report from sample data.

Setting a report as the home page:

The following example shows how to set a report as the home page based on a role. This example uses the 01. Geographic Results by Segment Report.

1. First, set up the role and create a sample user:
   a.  Create the role you want to use, for example, ROLE_REPORT_HOME.
   b.  Create a user HomeUser and add ROLE_REPORT_HOME to HomeUser.
2. Open the file \WEB-INF\jsp\modules\home\home.jsp in an editor and add the following lines:

```html
    <authz:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_REPORT_HOME"> 
    <c:redirecturl="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro-601/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Fpublic%2FSamples%2FReports&reportUnit=%2Fpublic%2FSamples%2FReports%2F01._Geographic_Results_by_Segment_Report"/> 
    </authz:authorize>
```

To find the URI for the report you want to use, open the report in the repository and copy the URI.

3. Save the modified file and restart the application server to see changes.
4. Log into JasperReports Server as HomeUser. The library page is displayed.

Comment: The way you above mentioned is not worked.Can I put that code in to anywhere in the home.jsp file? I think <authz is not working in my case.